# jhipster application files generated in wrong directory

Tags: yeoman, jhipster

When I try to create a jhipster application in ubuntu 13.10 with `yo jhipster` the generated output files are always dumped in the wrong directory.

For example I run `yo jhipster` in the directory `/mnt/mercury/jhipster-test/alpha` then the files are dumped out to `/mnt/mercury`. In fact if I run `yo jhipster` in any subdirectory of `/mnt/mercury` they are always dumped out to `/mnt/mercury`.

I'm using `yo version 1.1.2` from the standard ubuntu repository

Please advise how to generate files to be output in current directory.

For the benefit of anyone else facing this problem.
I managed to get Yeoman working with the following

```
npm cache clean

sudo npm rm -g yo

npm cache clean

sudo npm install -g yo
```

Comment: When you mean "root directory", you mean "/"? They should be generated in your current directory, of course

Comment: updated to show example of where files are being output

Comment: It's working fine on my machine: yo v.1.1.2, node v.0.10.24, jhipster v.0.7.1, Ubuntu 12.04LTS. I'm getting npm from ppa:chris-lea/node.js -> not the standard, which has an outdated node version. Can you check this?

Comment: I have the same setup with the ppa except using Ubuntu 13.10. I tried `yo webapp` and it behaves the same way dumping the files to `/mnt/mercury` instead of the subdirectory. So I'm guessing this is a yo problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this is a Yeoman problem on Ubuntu 13.10:

- We don't have this issue with Ubuntu 12.04
- There is the same issue with other generators ("yo webapp") on Ubuntu 13.10

As a workaround, I recommend you have a look at our Docker container:

https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-docker

This will allow you to run the full JHipster stack, with Ubuntu 12.04, inside a container! Just use it to generate the app, then you can work directly on your host machine.

Answer (score 10):

My problem: Accidentally "yo generating" in the parent directory.

Solution: Delete the `.yo-rc.json` file in the parent directory, then running the yo generator command in the child directory.

Comment: this save me, my classmate has this file in the user folder  for that always do a mess in that folder

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OSX Maverick with Node v0.10.26, yo v1.1.2 and generator-jhipster v0.11, the yo hipster command was generating all the sources always in the same (wrong!) directory and not using my current directory.
I fixed this problem doing the following:

```
 cd <WRONG_DIR_WHERE_CODE_IS_CREATED>
 rm .yo-rc.json node_modules/  
 npm uninstall -g karma
 npm install -g karma (Note: using sudo it was not working!)
 sudo npm install -g generator-jhipster
```

Not sure why but I've then been able to install karma and generator-jhipster again and suddenly yo hipster starting generating code again in my current directory

Could it be caused by different environment variables when launching npm with sudo?

Answer (score 0):

The file .yo-rc.json is hidden, if it is not deleted, the generator will constantly take the settings from it. You must delete .yo-rc.json.