# JHipster not generating to current directory

Tags: jhipster

I have installed JHipster on my Windows laptop using NPM according to the instructions here: http://www.jhipster.tech/installation/

In order to generate a JHipster Java project, I am making a new directory, changing into that directory and then issuing the JHipster command, as instructed here: http://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/

However, whatever directory I have moved to to when issuing the jhipster command, all artefacts are always created in the root of my C:/Users/ rather than the folder/directory I have navigated to.

This is very messy, any ideas what settings I can change to fix this?

Comment: First time, I hear of such thing. Which node version? Try running it again  in debug `jhipster --debug` or you could try using yo rather than the CLI to see if it makes a difference `yo jhipster`.

Comment: Do you have a `.yo-rc.json` file laying somewhere in parent folders of your project folder? Yo looks for one in current working directory and then upward until it finds one.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gaël, this was the right answer.  It is not possible to generate a JHipster project in a subfolder if it has already been used to create a project in a parent folder - even if you are in the subfolder it will just regenerate the parent one instead.

Comment: Yes you need an empty parent to combine several jhipster projects, maybe we could verify it and put a warning if such a file is found.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244032/jhipster-application-files-generated-in-wrong-directory . It seems like the same issue.